# Mongoose: define a schema property with one name in Document object and another in the actual database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have in my app multiple models defined for one collection: Trainee, Employee, Contractor, Manager, and Removed.

Each model schema has a date property that represents the time the person "entered" into the status represented by the model:

```js
const TraineeSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  accetedOn: Date,
  ...
});

const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  hiredOn: Date,
  ...
});

const ContractorSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  contractedOn: Date,
  ...
});

const ManagerSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  promotedOn: Date,
  ...
});

const RemovedSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  terminatedOn: Date,
  ...
});
```

In one case I perform an aggregation that filters data based on these properties. It would be a simpler code if all of these properties had the same name in the database. So, if for example, the data property is named `enteredIntoStatusOn` for all these schemas, I could just have:

```js
{ $match: { enteredIntoStatusOn: { $gt: ... } }
```

Is it possible to define in a schema a property that has one name when used in a mongoose Document object, but actually saved under a different name in the database?

I know I could do something similar using aliases. For example, I could define the manager schema with the `enteredIntoStatusOn` defined, and then also define a virtual field named `promotedOn` that simply gets and sets the `enteredIntoStatusOn` field. But then, both `promotedOn` and `enteredIntoStatusOn` are exposed in a document for the Manager model. Is there a way in Mongoose to just have the alias without the original property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to specify an alias in the schema:

```
let s = new Schema({
    n: { type: String, alias: "name" }
});
```

This automatically creates both getter and setter, so it is possible to use `name` everywhere instead of `n`.
You can read more about aliases [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases).

Comment: Wow. Totally missed that one in the documentation. Thanks!